# Undefined variable in Leaderboard(Unity and Php)

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

So here is my Php script for inserting the score from unity to php

```
<?php
// create the connection to our database with following values: location of our databse
// (with xampp it's "localhost"), next is the login ("name" and "password").
// if the connection can not be established we get an error message, that we've entered after "or die"
$sql_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id1151441_dbtest", "newcreator123") or die ("no DB Connection");

// after we're logged in, we can call our database
mysqli_select_db($sql_connect,"id1151441_dbtest123") or die ("DB not found");

// now we store our sent information from Unity in php variables, we can work with
if(isset(($_GET['newName']))){
    $name = $_GET['newName'];
}
if(isset($_GET['newScore'])){
    $score = $_GET['newScore'];
}

// Now we simply add/insert our values into our "highscores" table
// we first choose the columns and then add our values
// we don't need to fill in any value into the ID part, as it automatically gets a new value depending on the entries
mysqli_query($sql_connect,"INSERT INTO getdataofplayer (Name, Score) VALUES ($name,$score);");

// we're done now, so we can close the connection
mysqli_close($sql_connect);

?>
```

I have this error: 
*Undefined variable: name in /storage/h10/441/1151441/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 21*

**and on my Unity script for wwwform is this**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class HighScoreController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string Name;
    public int Score;
    public string db_url = "http://testleaderboard.000webhostapp.com";
    public GameObject textScreen;

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            SaveScore ();
        }
    }

    public void SaveScore(){
        StartCoroutine(SaveScores());
    }

    IEnumerator SaveScores(){
        // first we create a new WWWForm, that means a "post" command goes out to our database (for futher information just google "post" and "get" commands for html/php
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

        // with this line we will give a new name and save our score into that name
        // those "" indicate a string and attach the score after the comma to it
        form.AddField("newName", Name);
        form.AddField("newScore", Score);



        // the next line will start our php file that saves the Score and attaches the saved values from the "form" to it
        // For this tutorial I've used a new variable "db_url" that stores the path
        WWW webRequest = new WWW(db_url + "InsertScore.php", form);

        // with this line we'll wait until we get an info back
        yield return webRequest;
        if (webRequest.error != null) {
            Debug.Log (webRequest.error);
        } else {
            Debug.Log (webRequest.text);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadScores(){
        // we don't need to store any variable in this, just run the php file
        WWW webRequest = new WWW(db_url + "index.php");

        // now we wait again for the feedback of the command
        yield return webRequest;

        // this is a GUIText that will display the scores in game.
        textScreen.GetComponent<Text>().text = webRequest.text;
        Debug.Log (webRequest);
    }
}
```

I've been stuck for 5 hours just for this undefined variable error on my php script can someone please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use **[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Since you're creating the variables inside `if`--statements, the only reason for them to be undefined is if the `if`-statements doesn't validate as true. Dump/log the `$_GET` variable and check what it contains. You should probably also add a check to see if both variables are set before trying to update the DB.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i updated it to
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql_connect,$_GET['newName']);
    $score = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql_connect,$_GET['newScore']);

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's null sir . why is it null?
 Undefined index: userName in /storage/h10/441/1151441/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 25
NULL 

i var_dump($_GET['userName']); and i got that

Comment: **1.** You should use Prepared Statements instead (more secure). **2.** Unless `newScore` is a string, you shouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` since that is for... strings. Cast the score as integer instead:`$score = (int) $_GET['newScore'];`.(not needed when using Prepared Statements) **3.**  You need to put single quotes around string values in SQL `VALUES ('$name', ...)`. (not needed when using Prepared Statements) **4.** `isset()` will validate as false if the value doesn't exist _or_ is null.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson still have this error sir
Notice: Undefined index: newName in /storage/h10/441/1151441/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: newScore in /storage/h10/441/1151441/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 13
string(0) "" int(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding data to a form

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField("newName", Name);
    form.AddField("newScore", Score);

    WWW webRequest = new WWW(db_url + "InsertScore.php", form);
```

which you **post** to a URL. Your PHP should be `$_POST['newName']`, not `$_GET`. You use `$_GET` for getting variables in the URL, like if you'd use `WWW` like this:

```
new WWW(db_url + "InsertScore.php?newScore=10&newName=TheGinxx"
```

Which I don't recommend, I recommend you use your current code but change your `$_GET`s to `$_POST`s.

I'm not entirely sure that sql statement will work either, I usually encapsulate the variables with `' '`. So that'd be:

```
"INSERT INTO getdataofplayer (Name, Score) VALUES ('$name', '$score');"
```

for you, unless the `'` needs to be escaped, but I don't think so. I prefer always using `'` for strings as I've heard they're more performant since they don't need to check for variables, but don't quote me on that.

EDIT:

It appears OP didn't set the variables in the Unity editor.

Comment: It still undefined index on my InsertScore.php but on my index it adds a value 0 0 0 when i try this one sir
new WWW(db_url + "InsertScore.php?newScore=10&newName=TheGinxx"

Comment: I don't quite understand but my answer suggest that you change your php code's `$_GET` to `$_POST` and use the code you were using before.

Comment: the reason you're getting "unset variable" is because the variable isn't set. You're only creating the variable `if (isset($_GET['newName']))`, which is false because you're not sending GET-variables, you're sending POST-variables.

Comment: if(isset(($_POST['newName']))){
    $name = $_POST['newName'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['newScore'])){
    $score = $_POST['newScore'];
    }

Like this one ? already tried sir but it still null

Comment: You're declaring variables in the wrong scope. the $name only exist in the if-statement and will be forgotten after it is done. Do this: `$name = ""; if(isset(($_POST['newName']))){ $name = $_POST['newName']; }`. That way you can use it later as well. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: the problem was in my unity script sir. I was so dumb because it says null because it is empty from unity . Im so very idiot. Thanks sir

Comment: Haha, that was going to be my next question. Btw, that last thing I said was completely wrong - PHP doesn't care about that scope.

Comment: But did you need `$_POST` or did `$_GET` work with `WWWForm`?

Comment: $_POST[] or $_GET it still work on passing data through web sir . the only difference is the url when you use $_POST[] and $_GET[]